# How to assign default value when array has no value to compare in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hello I am new in angularjs I have following code, 
HTML

```
//here i have one more ng-repeat so comparing with this home.home_info_id to avgrating avg.home_inof_id
<div ng-repeat=' home in homeDetailInfo'>
    <div ng-repeat="avg in homerating">
      <div ng-if="avg.home_info_id==home.home_info_id">
        <div class="star" ng-modal="avg" data-score="{{avg.avg}}"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

here i am getting data as

```
hallrating=[
{"home_info_id":"94","avg":"3.33333333333333"},
{"home_info_id":"119","avg":"4"},
{"home_info_id":"95","avg":"4.5"}
]
```

So it works perfect for 3 homes but the problem is I have four homes,and the fourth home is not yet rated so I need to show data-score='0' for that home. 
I tried as follow

```
<div ng-repeat=' home in homeDetailInfo'>
        <div ng-repeat="avg in homerating">
          <div ng-if="avg.home_info_id==home.home_info_id">
            <div class="star" ng-modal="avg" data-score="{{avg.avg}}"></div>
          </div>
         <div ng-if="avg.home_info_id!=home.home_info_id && avg.avg!=''">
            <div class="star" ng-modal="avg" data-score="0"></div>
          </div>
        </div>

not worked for me i also tried
<div ng-repeat=' home in homeDetailInfo'>
        <div ng-repeat="avg in homerating">
          <div ng-if="avg.home_info_id==home.home_info_id">
            <div class="star" ng-modal="avg" data-score="{{avg.avg}}"></div>
          </div>
         <div ng-if="!avg.avg">
            <div class="star" ng-modal="avg" data-score="0"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: {{avg.avg || 0 }} ? avg.avg must be undefined... so maybe you can test it in a fiddle printing {{ avg.avg === undefined }}

Comment: Yeah its undefined only

Comment: so it must work.fiddle it. and what's "ng-modal" ? i suppose it's a typo error (ng-model ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div ng-repeat=' home in homeDetailInfo'>
  <div class="star" data-score="{{ getScore(home.home_info_id) }}"></div>
</div>
```

And then in your controller

```
$scope.getScore = function (homeInfoId) {
  var score = 0;

  homerating.forEach(function (rating) {
    if (rating.home_info_id === homeInfoId) {
      score = rating.avg;
    }
  }

  return score;
};
```

Comment: Great idea! thanks but you missed to complete that homerating.foreach(function(rating){
...
})
}
but I got your trick. many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method.

```
$scope.showScore = function(score) {
    if (angular.isDefined(score)) {
        return score;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And then in html

```
<div class="star" ng-modal="avg" data-score="showScore(avg.avg)"></div>
```

EDIT: Missed the () around avg.avg.

Comment: No sir thats not entering in function only I tried putting alerts in if and else. One more thing to be keep in mind is the function u called at data-score which means according to my code that will come inside only when I have home_info_id and avg, so I need to check something reverse of it.